# Find PID of conhost that runs python script

Tags: python-2.7

I have a question. When i run a python script a conhost.exe is created. Is there a possible way, inside a python script, to find out the PID of the conhost that runs my script?

Comment: You should probably give a lot more information about your situation. What platform are you running on. What the heck is "conhost.exe" and how does it relate to Python?

Comment: When you run a python script on windows a Console Windows Hosting is been created. This exe file is running your script. assuming you run a loop at the task manager you will see a python script with a specific PID and a conhost that "hosts" the script. those two have a link between them you can find via task manager the host witch running the script.  (Try it). Is there a possible way to find the PID of the host from Python?